# every case of switch is working in case of set

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, switch-statement, set

I am trying to use switch case in python for removal of elements from set but the problem is that every case of switch h is running

This I have tried this in python 3

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = set([1,2,3,4,6,5])
    d = 5


    switcher = {'pop':s.pop(),
                'remove':s.remove(5),
                'discard':s.discard(4)}
    switcher.get('remove', 'nothing')
    print(s)
```

{2, 3, 6}

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't have a `switch` statement. That's a dict. Also the `set([])` syntax is obsolete. Use `{}` instead.

```
s = {1,2,3,4,6,5}
```

If you want to delay evaluation of an expression, you can use a `lambda`.

```
switcher = {'pop': lambda: s.pop(),
            'remove': lambda: s.remove(5),
            'discard': lambda: s.discard(4)}
switcher.get('remove', 'nothing')()
```

Don't forget to call it when you do want it evaluated.

But there's a more common way of making a dict of functions with names: a class.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = {1,2,3,4,6,5}
    class Switcher:
        def pop():
            s.pop()
        def remove():
            s.remove(5)
        def discard():
            s.discard(4)
    Switcher.remove()
    print(s)
```

Notice these "methods" don't have a `self` parameter, so you don't need an instance. It's just a structure holding functions, like the lambda dict.

Comment: can we pass parameters in switcher = {'pop': lambda: s.pop(),
            'remove': lambda: s.remove(5),
            'discard': lambda: s.discard(4)}
switcher.get('remove', 'nothing')()

Comment: Lambdas can have parameters before the colon `(lambda x, y: x-y)(1, 2) == -1`.